# Можно ли итерировать данные получаемые при помощи функции?

Tags: python, dataframe

У меня есть 2 датафрейма

```
ma = [[2.0, 111], 
         [3.0, 222], 
         [4.0, 555], 
         [5.0, 888], 
         [6.0, 777]]
data2 = [[0, 2.0],
         [0, 3.0],
         [0, 4.0],
         [0, 5.0],
         [0, 6.0]]
columns1 = ['number', 'value']
columns2 = ['value', 'number']

ma = pd.DataFrame(np.array(ma), columns=columns1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data2), columns=columns2)
```

Также у меня есть функция

```
def numero(x):
    return ma.iloc[x-2]['value']
```

далее я пытаюсь напечатать список номеров из этого датафрейма на основе второго (`df2`):

```
for i in df2['number']:
    numero(i)
```

В итоге **TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key**

В чем дело? Ведь функция *numero* работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def numero(x):
    return ma.loc[x-2, "value"]
```